# Laravel 4 dynamic route with multiple segments

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, slug, laravel-routing

I would like to create a dynamic route that allows multiple segments.

```
example.com/segment1
example.com/segment1/segment2/
example.com/segment1/segment2/segment3
```

Using this:

```
Route::get('{slug}', 'PagesController@index');
```

Gives me my first dynamic segment and of course I could do this:

```
Route::get('{slug1}/{slug2}', 'PagesController@index');
```

and so on but I'm sure there's a better way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

I believe one complication when using `Route::get('{slug1}/{slug2}', 'PagesController@index');` would be handling all possible inputs so `segment1/segment2/` and also `foo/bar/`. You would probably end up with lots of unnecessary logic.

This may not be the best solution but I believe groups would work well for what you are trying to accomplish.

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'segment1'), function() {

    Route::get('/', 'ControllerOne@index');

    Route::group(array('prefix' => 'segment2'), function() {

        Route::get('/', 'ControllerTwo@index);
        Route::get('/segment3', 'ControllerThree@index');

    });
});
```

Maybe a little messy when only dealing with three examples but it could end up being beneficial and provide a nicer hierarchy to work with.

This also has the benefit for using `before` and `after` filters. Like for all `segment2` endpoints if you want to perform some filter, instead of adding the filter to all the individual endpoints you can just add it to the group!

```
Route::group(array('before' => 'someFilter', 'prefix' => 'segment2'), function() {
    // ... ...
});
```